# building new pc for coding requirements

Tags: pc

Requirements

- need to run 2 monitors - 1920X1080 and 1280x720 with recording @30fps
  during coding
- No or little gaming
- multitasking include coding on    android studio and watching videos
  on youtube running software like    VS code, IDE From JetBrains,
  Android Studio, BB FlashBack recorder    for screen capturing,
  general web development.

current parts
https://in.pcpartpicker.com/list/v2wnf8

Furthermore
There is a situation I need to handle. Here I am going with the R7 240 2GB DDR3 XFX card which has both HDMI and VGA outs. I have an old monitor HP w15e which has only VGA port. I am going to get a new monitor 1080p which is DELL-SE2216H and has both HDMI and VGA connection.

problem: I will use dell as primary monitor and hp as secondary using "extend display" feature on windows 10. I am thinking of connecting dell using HDMI and hp using VGA. Can i use both HDMI and VGA at the same time to extend the screen?

So on the desktop
HDMI from gfx card-->dell 1080p
VGA from gfx card-->hp 720p

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use both HDMI and VGA at the same time to extend the screen?

Yes, this will work fine. The card supports multi-monitor configurations and has the outputs you have said you will be using. As far as hardware goes, there is no reason that your proposed configuration would not work.

---

Edit: In response to your comments, here's my recommendation: [https://www.amazon.com/Gigabyte-DDR3-2GB-Graphics-GV-R724OC-2GI-REV2-0/dp/B00JRSPXMQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1504293362&sr=8-1&keywords=amd+R9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JRSPXMQ)

An R7 240 has all the ports you need, no adapters necessary, and it's a little more modern as far as a multi-monitor workstation / non-gaming card goes. It's not the newest thing out there but it's recent enough that it'll last longer than the card you posted about. It's also got better power efficiency than the card in the OP while meeting all of the required specs.

If that particular one sells out or something, you should be able to find some pretty similar cards by comparing the spec sheets. It may also help to compare the release dates for this card model to others, so you can find something from a similar generation. I'm recommending a card from around this time specifically because it will give you a good balance of pricing and longevity.

To answer your other questions, if you were to buy one of the more expensive cards you mentioned in the comments then I have two pieces of information to contribute. First, an RX 550 or a GTX 1050Ti is more power than you need, don't waste the money. If you do want to get one of those, then you just need a simple DVI -> VGA adapter. It's not an active adapter since the signal is going from digital to analog, the other way around you'd need a lightly more expensive active adapter.

Comment: as i am on a budget i am going with this card; i need to support both the screen at the same time while coding and recording the screen for teaching purpose at 30fps, is the card powerful enough for this or do i need to go with a GDDR5 card instead of ddr3; if there is a better card do suggest, this card is around 50usd here. Thanks

Comment: @Doc recording video is kind of a different ballpark. Please reply with the full system specs for the build and we can take a look at everything. www.pcpartpicker.com can help if you need a resource for listing everything. Also let me know if you are just recording so you can upload video later or if you are live streaming.

Comment: the part list is in the post, i'll be using bb flashback pro software to record the screen, i won't record game playing and won't stream. just screen capture at 30fps for coding tutorials. after recording the software allows me to edit the file and export as mp4 for viewing.

Comment: @Doc I'd recommend something a bit newer to be honest. Getting like an Nvidia gtx 750 or maybe even a 950 should be easy to find at the price range you're looking for.

Comment: i wont be gaming at all, i can have r7 240(in budget),or sapphire Rx 550  2gb(thrice the cost of R7- "no vga here") or zotac 1050Ti 4gb(4 times cost of r7)

Comment: only the r7 comes with vga port rx 550 and 1050ti don't have it.My hp monitor has only vga, the dell monitor has hdmi and vga.

Comment: also the rx 550 comes with dvi and hdmi but i have hdmi +vga on dell and vga on hp, how to deal with this if i go with rx 550?

Comment: @Doc please see my post edit for a full product recommendation as well as the answers to your questions posted here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Do i need to upgrade the power supply as the recommended card has a power requirement of 400W? Is 1Gb DDR5 better than 2GB ddr3? how is this card https://www.amazon.in/SAPPHIRE-GDDR5-BOOST-HDMI-DVI-D/dp/B00TIT3IKS/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1504325049&sr=8-1-fkmr1&keywords=r7+240+ddr5